# Is it possible to create a UNIQUE index on geometric types?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, unique-index

I have a table like

```
my_type | text
my_box  | box
```

where `my_box` is of type `box` from the [geometric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-geometric.html), and not from postgis.

I want a way to ensure that there are no duplicate boxes across all values of `my_type`. Usually, if it were an integer or somesuch, I'd just create a unique index across both columns. However, when trying to create an index on a box, I get

```
data type box has no default operator class for access method "btree"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Can I specify an operator class for the index? Do I cast the box as something else? (I'd like this solution to *also* apply to `polygon`, if possible) Do I create a function index?

Note that this is specifically NOT having to do with PostGis (unless that's the only way to do this - I'm not even sure if PostGis applies to geometric types). That's all that comes up when I google this, though.

Comment: You want a [GIST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) index

Comment: The answer below says `btree` is the only one available to do a unique constraint with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version Postgres 13 (as well as Postgres 12) supports the [index types `brin`, `gist` and `spgist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) for the built-in [geometric type `box`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.8). (No `btree` index.)

But none of these "access methods" (a.k.a. "index type") supports a `UNIQUE` constraint or index. `UNIQUE` is only implemented for `btree` indexes.

You can create a `UNIQUE` index on the text-representation of the value or a on hash value. There are many equivalent syntax variants for the same `box` value, but if you cast `box` to `text` you get the canonical form:

```
SELECT '((1, 1), (2, 2))'::box::text AS b1
     , '2, 2, 1, 1'::box::text AS b2;

     b1      |     b2
-------------+-------------
 (2,2),(1,1) | (2,2),(1,1)
```

#### Solutions

This `UNIQUE`, multicolumn, expression (`btree`!) index should work for you:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_box_uni ON tbl (my_type, (my_box::text));
```

I didn't spell out `btree`, as that's the default. And the only option for a `UNIQUE` index anyway.

It's unlikely that the canonical text representation of boxes will change in future versions, but I am also not aware of any guarantees.

To disallow any two boxes with the same `my_type` to *overlap* (a more common requirement!) use an [**exclusion constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). See:

- [Non-overlapping rectangles constrained to a boundary](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59402/3684)

This is much more restrictive, but *also* rules out exact duplicates.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e437105b47a4150518750b8ccf68d43e)*

Comment: Thanks! (extra chars...)

Comment: If the table has many rows (eg hundreds of millions), would it make sense to do some sort of function index, such that the index itself is smaller? (eg https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-expressional.html). Especially if I'll do it across more than 2 columns? Much obliged, thanks for your time!

Comment: @Hoopes: My unique index with a cast is just another "functional index" (= expression index). The cast is lossless. You might consider a hash function - at the cost of possible hash collisions. It all depends. On actual numbers (rows in table, cardinality in box column, expected growth / churn),  you willingness to risk hash collisions, performance characteristics and requirements, typical queries, available resources, read/write ratio, ... Here is a related answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684. You might ask a new question disclosing all relevant information.